# one ImageView object for multiple Imageview layouts

Tags: android, view, imageview

Can I use one ImageView object with multiple Imageview layouts. I have 4 different XML files,each with one imageview tag, that are inflated at different user conditions. but in my code I want to use only one ImageView object to dynamically assign image resource. but im not being able to do that, and for some reason , even after doing imgview = (ImageView) findViewbyId(R.mylayouts.customImage) for each layout that is inflated, it still shows the 1st image resource it was associated with. Please help. Below is the code for public Object instantiateItem of a pager view that im using.

```
public Object instantiateItem(View pager, int position) {
        View v = null;
        if (position == 0) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout1, null);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout2, null);

            if (mHelpImages1 == null) {  //int array to store image resourceID
                mHelpImages1 = new int[] { R.drawable.imageB1, R.drawable.imageB2 };
            }
            mImage1 = null;  //my imageView which i want to use everywhere
            mImage1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        } else if (position == 2) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.myLayout5, null);

            if (mHelpImages2 == null) {
                mHelpImages2 = new int[] { R.drawable.imageB3,
                        R.drawable.imageB4 };
            }

            String strNavi = getString(R.string.myString1) + "\n" + getString(R.string.myString2);
            mImage1 = null;
            mImage1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.myLayout3);
            mDesc2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.myString3);
            mDesc2.setText(strNavi);
        } else if (position == 3) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.myLayout6, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            tv.setSelected(true);
            tv.setSingleLine();
            tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);

            if (mHelpImages3 == null) {
                mHelpImages3 = new int[] { R.drawable.imageB7,
                        R.drawable.imageB8, };
            }
            mImage1 = null;
            mImage1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
        } 


        ScrollView scrollview = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
        try {
            if (scrollview != null) {
                scrollview.updateCustomEdgeGlow(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edge),
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edge2));
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "updateCustomEdgeGlow ERROR");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "updateCustomEdgeGlow Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ((ViewPager) pager).addView(v, 0);
        return v;
    }
```

> in the onPageSelected I do this

```
  public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    mPrevPosition = position;
    if (mHandler != null && mHandler.hasMessages(myMessage)) {
        mHandler.removeMessages(myMessage);
    }

    mSceneCount = 0;

    if (position != 0) {
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(myMessage, 0);
    }
}
```

> and the handler calls another function changeImage every 3 seconds which changes the imageResource of the imageView like this

```
private void changeImage() {

    if (mSceneCount == 100) {
        mSceneCount = 0;
    }

    switch (mPrevPosition) {
    case 1:
        if (mHelpImages1 != null) {
            int index1 = mSceneCount % mHelpImages1.length;
            Drawable mm = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
                    mBitmap.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), mHelpImages1[index1],
                            mImage1.getWidth(), mImage1.getHeight()));
            mImage1.setBackground(null);
            mImage1.destroyDrawingCache();
            mImage1.setBackground(mm);
            mm = null;
        }
        break;

        // and other switchcases here, but basically this is how i do it.


              default:
        break;
    }

    mImageCount++;
}
```

> Code works fine if i use multiple ImageView objects, i.e one ImageView for one layout.

Comment: Short answer, yes you can. Post your code and xml so we can see where your problem might be.

Comment: Hello soundConception, stackoverflow is blocked on my local network. Im using mobile internet so i cant post code as of now but i will asap. Till then can you give some link to refer to.

Comment: hey ive added my code, pls help me out

Comment: And your xml files are definitely correct? I notice for the case `(position == 2)` you have `mImage1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.myLayout3)`. Is `myLayout3` actually an ImageView?